# How to transfer deployed ERC20 token XZY in solidity?

Tags: solidity, tokens

In smart contract of solidity,  the following function will transfer `_amount` `ether` to a `recipient`:

```
function send(address recipient, uint _amount, uint256 _gas) private {
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{value:_amount, gas: _gas}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    }
```

by default, the value transferred is in `ether`. If an ERC20 token `XYZ` was deployed to address `_addressERC20`, how to transfer the token `XYZ` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
bool success = ERC20(_addressERC20).transfer(recipient, _amount);
```

Note that the contract will need to own at least `_amount` of the given token.

In other words, the following condition must hold before calling function `transfer`:

```
ERC20(_addressERC20).balanceOf(address(this)) >= _amount
```

Comment: Hi `goodvibration`,  is ERC20 the smart contract imported for the ERC20 token? So the question here is more about interaction between the ERC20 token contract and the smart contract which transfers this ERC20 token, isn't it? Many thanks.